# Passing data from python to c# using subprocess

Tags: python, c#

I am building a simple application for reading data from an Arduino board and displaying it with the help of c#. I read the output from the arduino board with the help of python, because I found it easier this way, and I am trying to send it to the c# app and display it on a label. I don't have much experience in either python or c#.

The code that I am trying to use is the following:

For python:

```py
import serial
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, bytesize=8)

p = Popen(r"C:\Users\User\source\repos\Program\Program\bin\Debug\Program.exe", 
stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    out, err = p.communicate(data)
    print(data)
```

For C#

```cs
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    while (true)
    {
        Stream ms = Console.OpenStandardInput();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ms);
        string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

        label1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

In python. I get the following error:

> ValueError: Cannot send input after starting communication

Any help or corrections to the code would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: why no directly get data from arduino, you have sample here  https://github.com/SolidSoils/Arduino ,either could you display a sample of data sent by python? string? integer, hexa...

Comment: your problem is not passing data to c# is first to read arduino from python..so if you dont directly read arduino from c# i suggest you to put off the tag c#

Comment: what is your program.exe?